# need help debugging PHP web application using netbeans-xdebug as my application freeze on reaching my class definition

Tags: php, netbeans

I am debugging my PHP wed application on netbeans IDE with netbeans-xdebug. My application freezes when its on the instruction that includes my class definition file. I don't see any error message (not sure where to look. sorry doing this whole process for the first time). How do i debug this?
I have generated my classes using db2php and included all the relevant files. I can step through all these classes while debugging before coming to my class at which point the whole things freezes. There are no error messages in the debug window

My class definition (generated by db2php plug-in and modified by me to add the constructor) is as below

```
class AptInfo extends Db2PhpEntityBase implements Db2PhpEntityModificationTracking {
    private static $CLASS_NAME='AptInfo';
    const SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE='`';
    const SQL_TABLE_NAME='apt_info';
    const SQL_INSERT='INSERT INTO `apt_info` (`apt_id`,`house_number`,`block`,`apt_area`,`apt_type`,`apt_usage`,`owner_id`,`tenant_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    const SQL_INSERT_AUTOINCREMENT='INSERT INTO `apt_info` (`house_number`,`block`,`apt_area`,`apt_type`,`apt_usage`,`owner_id`,`tenant_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    const SQL_UPDATE='UPDATE `apt_info` SET `apt_id`=?,`house_number`=?,`block`=?,`apt_area`=?,`apt_type`=?,`apt_usage`=?,`owner_id`=?,`tenant_id`=? WHERE `apt_id`=?';
    const SQL_SELECT_PK='SELECT * FROM `apt_info` WHERE `apt_id`=?';
    const SQL_DELETE_PK='DELETE FROM `apt_info` WHERE `apt_id`=?';
    const FIELD_APT_ID=536777627;
    const FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=702030574;
    const FIELD_BLOCK=987946407;
    const FIELD_APT_AREA=447002381;
    const FIELD_APT_TYPE=447575482;
    const FIELD_APT_USAGE=990668577;
    const FIELD_OWNER_ID=828356301;
    const FIELD_TENANT_ID=-1961505558;
    private static $PRIMARY_KEYS=array(self::FIELD_APT_ID);
    private static $AUTOINCREMENT_FIELDS=array(self::FIELD_APT_ID);
    private static $FIELD_NAMES=array(
        self::FIELD_APT_ID=>'apt_id',
        self::FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=>'house_number',
        self::FIELD_BLOCK=>'block',
        self::FIELD_APT_AREA=>'apt_area',
        self::FIELD_APT_TYPE=>'apt_type',
        self::FIELD_APT_USAGE=>'apt_usage',
        self::FIELD_OWNER_ID=>'owner_id',
        self::FIELD_TENANT_ID=>'tenant_id');
    private static $PROPERTY_NAMES=array(
        self::FIELD_APT_ID=>'aptId',
        self::FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=>'houseNumber',
        self::FIELD_BLOCK=>'block',
        self::FIELD_APT_AREA=>'aptArea',
        self::FIELD_APT_TYPE=>'aptType',
        self::FIELD_APT_USAGE=>'aptUsage',
        self::FIELD_OWNER_ID=>'ownerId',
        self::FIELD_TENANT_ID=>'tenantId');
    private static $PROPERTY_TYPES=array(
        self::FIELD_APT_ID=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_INT,
        self::FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_STRING,
        self::FIELD_BLOCK=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_STRING,
        self::FIELD_APT_AREA=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_INT,
        self::FIELD_APT_TYPE=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_STRING,
        self::FIELD_APT_USAGE=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_STRING,
        self::FIELD_OWNER_ID=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_INT,
        self::FIELD_TENANT_ID=>Db2PhpEntity::PHP_TYPE_INT);
    private static $FIELD_TYPES=array(
        self::FIELD_APT_ID=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_INTEGER,10,0,false),
        self::FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_VARCHAR,10,0,false),
        self::FIELD_BLOCK=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_VARCHAR,3,0,false),
        self::FIELD_APT_AREA=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_INTEGER,10,0,true),
        self::FIELD_APT_TYPE=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_CHAR,6,0,true),
        self::FIELD_APT_USAGE=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_CHAR,14,0,true),
        self::FIELD_OWNER_ID=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_INTEGER,10,0,true),
        self::FIELD_TENANT_ID=>array(Db2PhpEntity::JDBC_TYPE_INTEGER,10,0,true));
    private static $DEFAULT_VALUES=array(
        self::FIELD_APT_ID=>null,
        self::FIELD_HOUSE_NUMBER=>'',
        self::FIELD_BLOCK=>'',
        self::FIELD_APT_AREA=>null,
        self::FIELD_APT_TYPE=>null,
        self::FIELD_APT_USAGE=>null,
        self::FIELD_OWNER_ID=>null,
        self::FIELD_TENANT_ID=>null);
    private $aptId;
    private $houseNumber;
    private $block;
    private $aptArea;
    private $aptType;
    private $aptUsage;
    private $ownerId;
    private $tenantId;

        public function __construct($block, $housenumber, $owner_id = NULL, $aptArea=NULL, $aptType=NULL, $aptUsage=NULL, $tenant_id = NULL) {
            $this->block = $block;
            $this->houseNumber = $housenumber;
            $this->ownerId = $owner_id;
            $this->aptArea = $aptArea;
            $this->aptType = $aptType;
            $this->aptUsage = $aptUsage;
            $this->tenantId = $tenant_id;
            $this->aptId = NULL;
        }
// there is lot more code here (set and get functions for each variable which i am skipping for the sake of this question
}
```

I am new to debugging PHP so not sure how/where to look for errors hence pardon if this is a rather silly question

thanks in advance
chetana

Comment: Ok i found the answer on how to see the error messages. They are displayed on the browser window. However we need to set the variable display_errors=On in php.ini its off by default

Once i see the error message its clear where i had gone wrong in the class definition
In the above case i had made a type in the include file name and hence was not able to find the definition of Db2PhpEntityModificationTracking class

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer on how to see the error messages. They are displayed on the browser window. However we need to set the variable display_errors=On in php.ini its off by default Once i see the error message its clear where i had gone wrong in the class definition In the above case i had made a type in the include file name and hence was not able to find the definition of Db2PhpEntityModificationTracking class